# Angular getRawValue() does not fetch [values] from reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular reactive form on which apart from many other controls I have two that I can’t get the value of onSubmit().

See Val1 and Val2:

```
buildForm() {
        this.createRequestForm = this.form.group({
            Name: ['', [Validators.required, CustomValidatorService.validateCharacters]],
            Comments: ['', [CustomValidatorService.validateCharacters]],
         …
            Val1: [{ value: '', disabled: true }],
            Val2: [{ value: '', disabled: true }],
```

HTML:

```
<input name="Val1" matInput formControlName="Val1" placeholder="Val 1" [value]="valModel?.val1">
```

...and same for val2.

Here’s the way I populate the val1 and val2

```
    this.createRequestForm.get('Name').valueChanges
        .subscribe(value => {
            if (value && value.length === 6) {
                this.commonHttpService.getValDetails(value)
                    .subscribe(valModel => this.valModel = valModel);
            }
        });
```

As you can see the values for val1 and val2 come from a http call, that binds theresults to this.valModel and thn it automatically populates the form.

Everything works fine, the values are populated on the screen but when I am trying to submit the form using

> .getRawValue()

it shows val1=”” and same for val2…

I guess it is the way I bind those values to controls?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> this.createRequestForm.value.val1

to fetch value of createRequestForm (form) fields

Comment: Is that the only way? Im sending JSON away and woudl have to be doing some stitching to get these included...I was thinking maybe something is wrong with the way I have those controls wired up and fixing up html would include those values in the form...

Comment: also define a function   get f() {
    return this.createRequestForm.controls; } and use function to fetch values in reactive forms

Comment: there can be many ways but i have shared what I have used in my reactive form if you want i can share my code.

Comment: I'm just going to go with what I previously thought of doing... i will assign these values manually in the http call subscription... eg:
this.createRequestForm.get('Val1').setValue(this.valModel.val1);
and same for val2. 
Thanks though.